# Как удалить текст из картинки?

Tags: php

возможно ли вообще с помощью php удалить (или частично замазать) текст который находится на картинке? Дайте направление - куда копать?

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит примерно так - есть 99% картики. Можно ли восстановить недостающий 1%. В общем случае - нет. В некоторых часных случаях, если удаётся распознать и текст и изображение под ним - с какой-то вероятностью можно. Там... например если текст написан на треугольнике, и точно извесно что на картинке треугольник.

Comment: Если есть возможность распознать текст - то можно вычислить участок - соответственно - размыть участок можно.

Comment: Вроде в вопросе не указано как замазать текст. С помощью библиотеки gd можно прямоугольную область закрасить в любой цвет.